# index estimation for a list of datetimes in python

Tags: python, function, datetime

So I have a function that takes the following: `times` = a list of datetime objects, `start` = a datetime object, and `end` = a datetime object. and returns a list that are the datetime objects **between** start and end

```
def func(times,start,end):
    return times[start:end],(times.index(start),times.index(end))
```

I need it to be able to still work if `start` and/or `end` are not actually in the list of datetime objects: `times`.

So if `start` is not in the list, it would take the first item that is "larger than" `start`, and it would do the same if `end` is not in the list, except it would be "less than" instead.

It is also crucial that I get the indices of the actual starting point ending point.

**What do I add to my function that will do that?**

Comment: is your `times` sorted when you call `func(times, start, end)` ?

Comment: yes it is and it always will be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bisect

```
import bisect
def func(times, start, end):
    bucket = [start, end]
    out = [x for x in times if bisect.bisect(bucket, x) is 1 or x in bucket]
    return out, (times.index(out[0]), times.index(out[-1]))
```

Comment: He needs the indices in the result

Comment: times.index() always returns the index of the first occurrence. If the `times` list has more than one objects with the same value as `end`, only the first one is returned by your function.

Answer (score 0):

A naive approach for this question:

```
def func(times, start, end):
    s = 0
    e = len(times)-1

    while s < len(times) and times[s]< start: 
        s+=1

    while e >= 0 and times[e] > end: 
        e-=1

    if (e < 0 or s >= len(times) or s > e): 
        return None

    return times[s:e+1], (s,e)
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not simply `[dt for dt in times if dt >= start and dt <= end]`